# How to overwrite a numpy file?

Tags: numpy

Currently I have a program that is supposed to overwrite a certain numpy file, however, it is unable to overwrite it for some reason.
Heres an example:

```
img = np.random.rand((100,100))
np.save('./f.npy',img)
img=np.load('./f.npy')
c1 = img.copy()
img = np.zeros((100,100))
img+=1000000
np.save('./f.npy',img)
print(np.load('./f.npy'),img)==c1)
```

outputs true
Is there a way to overwrite a numpy file?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here because I am unable to reproduce this. I do get False when I try this out. Which version of numpy are you using? Because there are a couple of your syntax that is at least not supported by the latest numpy. `np.random.rand((100,100))` should not work; you are passing the args as a tuple. It should be passed comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely just becasue some unmatched brackets. Try replacing the last line with this.

`print(np.all(np.load('./f.npy')==c1))`. This should print out False.